# Scrape API protected by cloudflare, XHR pass but python request with 403

Tags: python, request, xmlhttprequest, cloudflare, scrape

I am trying to scrape a web api protected by cloudflare. I am able to fetch the result in browser by making xmlhttprequest. However, I received error 403 when doing the same request. I specified same user agent and etc. Anyone knows any hints? Thanks

Comment: I think you should provide more context for your question, is not very clear and you are not definitely showing anything that you have done. But you could improve it, in that way you will get more meaningful response. Respect to your question, it could be for example that you are not providing a token that is necessary to access that particular resource of the API. But again, is too broad your question

Comment: cloudflare has variety firewall rules.maybe you should copy all param from the browser's request header